# testng - Get name of the class that contains failed test

Tags: java, selenium, testng

```
<test name="Test">
   <classes>
     <class name="io.test.FirstTest"/>
   </classes>
</test>
```

I want to  get name of the FirsTest class without the package name inside `onTestFailure`. In other wors, I need to get `FirstTest`, not `io.test.FirstTest`.  How to do so?

```
   public class TestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult testResult) {

    }
  }
```

I have used `testResult.getInstanceName()`, but it returns  `io.test.FirstTest`. Therefore, I have used `string.substring()`:

```
   final String name = testResult.getInstanceName();
   final String result = name.substring(navn.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).trim();
```

But is there a better solution?

Comment: perform a split on the name, split on delimiter "."' and the last element of your row is what you need

Comment: Try : testResult.getSimpleName()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```java
package click.webelement.testng;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Listeners({TListenerTest.class})
public class TListenerTest implements ITestListener {

    @Test
    public void toFail(){
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println(result.getInstance().getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(result.getTestClass().getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

However I would not rely on the "simple names". They look nice unless you run into dups sooner or later (since you wouldn't be able to distinguish classes with the same name but from different packages).